NET lock / protect for read only access?
Is it necessary to use lock, Interlocked or other protection if multiple threads are only reading from int/double variable or object like Hashtable, ArrayList? Values are assigned before additional threads are started.

No. If there are no writers concurrent with readers then you don't need to lock.
However, it would be better if the data does not change to use read-only or frozen collections. That way a future change to the code will not introduce problems without having to do wider changes.
Even better would be custom wrappers based on read-only collections: that gives you a level of abstraction that would, usually, make such future changes easier.
